# RuTube MPMoviePlayerController initWithContentURL:

Tags: ios, xcode, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am trying to play a video from url and the only thing i am getting is a black screen and a loading wheel?
I have a [XML/JSON](http://rutube.ru/api/video/99d57beca71bff47891b0c5546bf903c/?format=xml) from witch i need somehow to play the video,
I tried with all 3 links i have there and no response

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://rutube.ru/play/embed/7224398"];
moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:url];
[moviePlayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x , self.view.frame.origin.y, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
[self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
[moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES];
[moviePlayer setShouldAutoplay:YES];
```

Is there a chanse to start this video using MPMoviePlayerController ??

P.S: I managed to load the video in a WebView but its not what i need.

Comment: You probably need an access to the .mp4 file rather than an embed player

Comment: the XML file is all that i have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to extract direct link to .mp4 file somehow.
Check this [article](http://tradiz.org/Rutube/Skachivanie-s-rutuberu-po-rtmp-ssylkam).